# How to redirect a user off a page by user role?

Tags: php, wordpress

A lot of these guides are 'redirect after login' I have mulitple user types with different levels of access, I'd like to write some code which if a 'Subscriber' role goes onto the page (Which they do not have access it'll redirect them.

Here's one of the many code snippets I've tried, but can't get it to work! Help :)

```
function consultant_page_redirect() {
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $role_name = $current_user->roles[0];

  if (('subscriber' === $role_name ) &&( is_single( array(2864, 2630))  ) ) {
    wp_redirect('/trial-user-page/');
  }

}
```

Comment: Where in your theme(?) did you put this code? I.e. where are you calling this function?

Comment: apologies it's on a custom plugin and I've missed out the add_action line which called the function

Answer (score 0):

```
function consultant_page_redirect( $user_login, $user ) {
    $role_name = $user->roles[0];

  if (('subscriber' === $role_name ) &&( is_single( array(2864, 2630))  ) ) {
    wp_redirect('/trial-user-page/');
  }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'consultant_page_redirect', 10, 2);
```

Add this snippet code on child theme functions.php

Comment: Hi there thanks for this but it doesn't seem to work? We're running a gensis theme if that helps